# Python Running C++ Extension Crashes On Mac M1 ARM

Tags: python, c++, macos, arm64

Recently moved from Mac Intel to M1 processor and have not been able to find anything anywhere to help resolve an issue I've been having with one of my Python programs that utilizes a C++ extension.

I use distutils to compile the C++ code into a darwin.so binary file. The first time I setup my environment and compiled the binary, I had no issue. However, after making changes to the C++ code and compiling a new binary, executing the corresponding Python code crashes with little information as to why. In the Console, I can sometimes see reports showing "Code Signature Invalid". In Terminal, it just says "zsh: killed python xxxxxx.py". My project is setup in a virtual environment using Conda Miniforge.

If I restart the Mac and run the Python again, no such crash occurs and the C++ code changes I had made from the previous compile are functional. If I make a subsequent change to the C++ code it crashes again until restarting.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the solution, I posted the above question in case someone else by chance encountered the same thing.

After various tests, I determined my problem was that my distutils setup script was using shutil.copy to move the newly compiled binary to a different location that the Python code was looking for. I don't have an understanding as to why, but I found that the problem went away if the setup script would first delete the old binary with os.remove prior to copying the new one. My guess is the code signature on the darwin.so file was retaining some old information when it was being replaced by the copy.

I don't know if this actually had anything to do with the M1 processor or was actually related to the operating system (Monterey). My previous Intel Mac that did not have this issue was running Catalina.